# Is there a quick way to check if element doesn’t displayed using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am checking that under some conditions `button` element shouldn’t be displayed.

I use the following code but it lasts for 40 seconds. I need it to be quicker.

```
try {
  addAnotherScenarioButton.click();
  return true;
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
  log.debug("Creating scenario button is not displayed");
  return false;
}
```

Here is the log result:

```
13:26:33 DEBUG: Checking visibility for creating scenario button
 
13:27:13 DEBUG: Creating scenario button is not displayed
```

Comment: Plz send us the linkon the page you are trying to do this propably you are not trying the right xpath

Comment: Hi @YourHelper it's an internal link so it will not be visible
But the question is why java or selenium wait 30 sec while catching an exception?

It is a case about role model checks - I open the page and should check that not all menu items are visible ?

It will never appear as it supposed to waitUntilMethod

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Your xpath"));
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Your xpath")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Your xpath"))
));
```

Comment: In my case, there is no such element before I start to check it.
And this check go to TimeOutException after a period of more than 10 sec